# Populating table view with data

Tags: swift

so im trying to populate the rows in my table with the information stored in array of "events". where events is an object that has location and title data. for some reason im getting a bad instruction error thread 1 at the line thats commented. Any idea why?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {// this sets the title and subtitle to the Title and Location in the given EventPlan
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.EventCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = eventsArray[indexPath.row].title // Error here

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = eventsArray[indexPath.row].location
    return cell        
}
```

Comment: probably your cell is `nil`, check if its being created

Comment: Are you sure you have enough elements in `eventsArray`? If `indexPath.row` is 8, you'll need 9 elements in there, and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your number of rows for section data source call, make sure that you're returning eventsArray.count